# How I can get access to dynamic input value in select2 widget?

Tags: input, widget, jquery-select2

Maybe someone has faced such a problem. To make the select2 widget work, I use the following code:

```
<link href="https://www.malketiya.com/listgrid/DropDown.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://www.malketiya.com/listgrid/DropDown.js"> </script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="selectBox0" onchange="changeFunc0();">
<option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
<option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<script>
var selectedValue1;
var selectedValue0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({tags: true});
});
</script>
```

I can write my own tag dynamically because `tags: true`.

[image]

For example, I write "fff". How can I save this in a variable use `OnInputEvent` without click on "fff" option in the drop menu?
I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need make id for

```
<input class="select2-search__field" id="s2sf" type="search".../>
```

and then

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function (e) { 
var x = document.getElementById("s2sf").value; alert(x); 
});
```